# Conversion failed when casting from nvarchar to int in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON CONVERT(INT,T1.DeviceID)=T2.LogicalDeviceId
```

`LogicalDeviceId` is in ***int*** and `DeviceID` in ***string***

> error :Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'NA' to
>   data type int.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Uhm, could it be that this actually needs the sql-server tag instead of mysql?

Comment: @LukStorms - also possible. The current syntax is TSQL valid. he need to check the tags again.

Comment: Do it by hand. If someone tells you that something's value is `NA`, how do *you* convert that into an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default the 'NA' to NULL.
A NULLIF can be used for that.

This works in MS Sql Server.

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 t1
JOIN T2 t2
  ON t2.LogicalDeviceId = CONVERT(INT, NULLIF(t1.DeviceID, 'NA'));
```

In MS SQL Server 12+ & Azure SQL Database you could use a [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql).
Which instead of an error, will return NULL if the conversion fails.

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 t1
JOIN T2 t2
  ON t2.LogicalDeviceId = TRY_CONVERT(INT, t1.DeviceID);
```